# How do I kill a summoned ender dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been wanting to kill my ender dragon in my world that I summoned. I tried:

```
/kill @e[type=EnderDragon,r=100]
```

and

```
/kill @e[type=EnderDragon]
```

But neither of them worked! Any other ways I could kill it?

Answer (score 10):

The correct entity type is [ender_dragon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values/Entity_IDs) and not EnderDragon.
So, use `/kill @e[type=ender_dragon]`

Comment: Vote this as answer, if this worked for you.

Answer (score -3):

Use a sword that has Fire Aspect II, Sharpness V, Looting III And Knockback II.